# NodeJS - output json array as mutiple json files to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I try to use NodeJS to read a JSON array from a JSON file, and then output each JSON object multiple JSON files to the disk.

However, I got the Error EMFILE: too many open files

The array has 20,000 objects.

The code:

```
function main(){
var clusters_statistics=require("cluster_whole_1.json");
for(var i=0; i<clusters_statistics.length; i++){
    var fs=require('fs');
    var outputFilename='cut_json/'+i+'.json';
    fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(clusters_statistics[i], null, 4), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Update:
1. I tried to use the close() function as suggested by Gustavo, unfortunately, it still says "there are too many files open". ("Open" this time).
2. Then I tried recursion inside the close(), and it works now.

The code:

```
function main(){
    clusters_statistics=require("cluster_whole_1.json");
    call_close(clusters_statistics.length);
}

function call_close(i){

    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = 'cut_json/'+i+'.json';

    fs.open(path, "w+", function(error, fd) {
        if (error) {
            console.error("open error:  " + error.message);
        }else {
            fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(clusters_statistics[i], null, 4), function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {

            }
        }); 

        fs.close(fd, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
              if(i<=0){
                  return;
              }else{
                  if(i%100==0){
                      console.log(i);
                  }
                  call_close(i-1);
              }
            }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You may will have to do it sequentially, at least in groups.  I guess that would mean recursion instead of a for loop.

Comment: Also, you should probably move [var fs = require('fs')] above the for loop.

Comment: Hi Jarek, thank you. I tried to use the recursion inside the close() function. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Close the file after you finish writing the Jason into it.

Now you are keeping the files open and filling the memory,  if you don't close them manually they will only be closed when your program finishes​.

> ```
> var fs=require('fs');
> function main(){
>     var clusters_statistics=require("cluster_whole_1.json"); for(var i=0; i<clusters_statistics.length; i++){ 
>     var outputFilename='cut_json/'+i+'.json';
>     var my_file = fs.open(outputFilename, 'w+');
>     var buffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(clusters_statistics[i], null,4):
>     fs.write(my_file, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err, written, buffer) {
>         if(err) {
>             console.log(err);
>         } else {
>             console.log('OK!'); 
>         }
>     });
>     fs.close(my_file);
> }
> ```

Comment: I am not sure that it will be enough.  He is calling writeFile async so the files are opening very fast, but maybe.

Comment: Hi, sorry.. it says "throw new TypeError('callback must be a function');"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the buffer to the fs.write call

Comment: Hi Gustavo, thank you. Unfortunately, it still returns the same error. Sorry I am not familiar with this. I tried to use recursion as suggested by Jarek, and recall the function inside close(). And it works for me now. Not sure whether it wastes some time (it might, but at least it works.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing the file descriptor is not necessary when using `fs.writeFile`, but you'll probably want to write the files sequentially so you don't open too many files at once.

```
function write_cluster_statistics(clusters_statistics, callback, index) {
    index = index || 0;

    if (index >= clusters_statistics.length) {
        return callback();
    }

    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = 'cut_json/' + index + '.json';
    var content = JSON.stringify(clusters_statistics[index], null, 4);
    fs.writeFile(path, content, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            write_cluster_statistics(clusters_statistics, callback, index + 1);
        }
    });
}

function main() {
    var clusters_statistics = require("cluster_whole_1.json")
    write_cluster_statistics(clusters_statistics, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
}
```